# (C#) Copying User Selected File To AppData Folder

Tags: c#, replace, copy, rename

Okay, so. I'm going to try to explain this as best as I can.

I have been working on a program, obviously. Basically, the user selects one file hits the "Replace" button and it replaces the files in a AppData folder.

Well, I got how to make an AppData folder for my program. 
Basically, what I would like to do is first off take the selected file (that's through the open file dialog) and copy to the AppData that I created for one. Then I need to rename the file and copy the file to the other folder.

I've been looking and can't seem to find what I need...which sucks.

EDIT:
My second question. Say the user chooses "myfile.txt" there's a folder in the AppData at ".../Roaming/thefiles/file.txt"

I need to rename and replace that "file.txt", but I can not figure out how to move to that directory since everyone's username is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you dont need to create a folder in AppData it will be readily available.

```
File.Copy(sourcepath,destinationpath); can be used for this purpose
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx check this out.

use `Application.UserAppDataPath` or `Application.CommonAppDataPath` to access your program's app data folder.

You can call:

```
File.Copy(sourcepath,Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath,"yourfile.ext"));
```

### Edit

I understand you mean logged in user of the system:

```
using (OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fullFileName = fd.FileName;
        string fileNameWithExt = Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
        string destPath = Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath, fileNameWithExt);
        File.Copy(fd.FileName, destPath);
    }
}
```

the above code would copy the selected file to `AppData` path of your Program that belongs to logged in user, ex: if you logged in as user1 to windows this will be copied under user1's `AppData`.

### Edit2

If am not mistaken then `Application.UserAppDataPath` will always give the path of current logged user of windows, so without worrying of losing other user's data you can safely move the file inside that Directory.

Comment: Okay, but let me ask this. The source path would be user selected, how could I code that in?
Then destination path is a folder in appdata but the user is different for everyone. How could I access that specific folder?

Comment: above code will allow user to select a file and it will be copied to AppData, your second question is not clear pls give more info which file you want to replace?

Comment: I could not edit my comment. But how do I make it go under an AppData folder that was already created when program is run? Using the code you gave me. And the file needs to delete, or moved (probably moved), when the "Replace" button is hit or program is exited.

Comment: that directory will be created on demand only, when you call Application.UserAppDataPath if directory doesnt exist it will create one.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Does UserAppDataPath alllow for sub directories to be accessed so that it can drill down to the last one and replace the directory with the one copied from the source path?